# euler angle to "KML" view angles

Tags: view, kml, translate, angle

Does anyone have a good description or reference for how to convert between ECI Euler Angles to KML View Angles? Any help is good help. Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "ECI"?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the KML specification states about kml:Model:

> ```
> The structure and appearance of the textured 3D object are not defined in this specification.
> ```

However Google Earth roughly models the appearance by applying roll, tilt then heading rotations (in this specific order). I found this out by trial and error, since the GE docs don't describe this anywhere. Unfortunately GE's orientation calculation is buggy and sometimes it spins things by 180 or spins the wrong way or spins a small amount in another axis - this is a known behaviour.